# "connect: Bad file descriptor" postgresql log file

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgresql 9.1 server and a few times now the hard drive on the server has become completely full for no valid reason. I checked to see what is taking so much space using the following command

```
du -a /var | sort -n -r | head -n 10
```

and it turns it's the postgresql-9.1-main.log file

when I do `cat postgresql-9.1-main.log` there is a endless print of

```
connect: Bad file descriptor
connect: Bad file descriptor
connect: Bad file descriptor
connect: Bad file descriptor
connect: Bad file descriptor
connect: Bad file descriptor
connect: Bad file descriptor
connect: Bad file descriptor
connect: Bad file descriptor
connect: Bad file descriptor
```

I want to make sure this does not happen ever again. I'm not sure what this log message really means. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I had the same problem. The postgres-main.log file was getting so big (35GB per day) . I haven't solved the issue yet, but I have disabled the postgres logging and the message has gone. At least, the server is running well (apparenly). If you want to disable the logging, just add the paremeter "log_min_error_statement = PANIC" to your postgresql.conf, which will turn of the logging.

Comment: @RodrigoAlmeida are you also using postgresql 9.1? I wonder if upgrading would solve the issue.

Comment: No, i'm not. I'm using 8.4 version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found it was because Postgres was being used to run malicious software. I changed postgresql.conf so connections could only be made locally, removed the exec111() function and the files from /tmp and have not had any problems since.
See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246735/releasing-a-deleted-but-open-log-file 
Answer starting "You have a bigger problem than Out of Disk my friend!"